# Why aren't double migrations supported?

Tags: support, migration

My [latest question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45897/im-using-a-shared-server-and-as-such-gmail-marks-my-email-as-spam-all-from-he) was migrated from Superuser to WebApps, per someone's suggestion on meta.

Then, in WebApps, they told me [it would do better in WebMasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50035/im-using-a-shared-server-and-as-such-gmail-marks-my-email-as-spam-all-from-he). However, they couldn't migrate it twice. They instead had to close it on WebApps and told me to simply re-post it in WebMasters, losing the comments on it and causing my account on WebApps to have a closed question listed. Is there any reason a moderator can't double migrate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's to prevent sites from playing hot potato with bad questions, all trying to pass them off to some other site rather than just closing them.  There have been problems in the past where particular sites tend to just migrate bad or improper questions to another site, thus adding a significant amount of moderator work to that other site to deal with the question.

Comment: Double migrations also break links. We automatically redirect from the source site to the destination, but once there's another migration hop, things get even more confusing/broken for the asker and future readers.

Comment: This even happens with the one hop. SO sends (or at least used to) a lot of meh to nonsence questions to Programmers under the reasoning that they are "conceptual".

Comment: @Linuxios Yep, and then programmers would send it right back, and everyone involved would just be annoyed.  This is one of many steps taken to avoid migrating garbage.

Comment: @Servy: Let's start an SE dodequestion game. If you get hit with a bad question, you're out. First up, SO vs. Programmers. Soon it will be the most popular sport on SE. ;)