# Remove "(already migrated)" from Meta while closing migrated question

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, close-dialog, migration

When voting to close any migrated question on Meta, it shows "*(already migrated)*" in off-topic reason which is actually wrong since we can't migrate any question from Meta Stack Overflow.

[image]

This is similar to: ["(too old to migrate)" shouldn't show on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186927/187824)

Can we remove that text please?

Comment: This is a little bit different from the `(too old to migrate)`. Closing migrated questions would cause the migration to be rejected, and such questions will be unlocked on the originating site.

Comment: @Antony - that means *(already migrated)* text is required here?

Comment: It's probably just because [double migrations aren't supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185839/why-arent-double-migrations-supported) and the code is the same everywhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, this shouldn't be there. Fixed yet again in the next build.